# Pass an expression as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass an expression as parameter to a function like:

```
public string MyFunction(bool expression) //what should I set here as parameter type?
{
    return expression ? "True" : "False";
}

public void InvokeMyFunction()
{
    var myString = MyFunction(10 > 1);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a bigger use case than this or are you just trying to return a  boolean as a string?

Comment: Have you tried this to see what the result is ?

Comment: @Sayse A bigger case, this was just an example what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: So are you trying to pass the expression "10 > 1" or do you want to pass the result of the expression (true).

Comment: What *are* you trying to achieve? The code you've written compiles already - so what doesn't it do that you want it to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `Func<bool>` to represent a method that returns a boolean. Also when you declare the function, you can use lambda syntax `() =>` to represent an anonymous method.

```
string MyFunction(Func<bool> expression)
{
    return expression() ? "True" : "False";
}

void InvokeMyFunction()
{
    var myString = MyFunction(() => 10 > 1);
}
```

Comment: This passes a delegate instance whose underlying method is the anonymous method created with the `=>` arrow (lambda). It does not actually pass an "expression". There is the `Expression<Func<bool>>` for passing a tree representation of an expression. But since the question is vague, we do not know if that is useful in @NaughtyNinja's application.